# Intercalação de dois arrays (vetores) em C#

Tags: c#, array, .net, algoritmo

Meu código possui dois *arrays* de 5 elementos, um *array* possui números ímpares enquanto o outro possui números pares e é necessário **realizar uma intercalação entre eles**, eu criei um terceiro vetor para fazer isso, mas o resultado não é o esperado.

A entrada:

```
Digite o 0° número do vetor 1: 1
Digite o 1° número do vetor 1: 3
Digite o 2° número do vetor 1: 5
Digite o 3° número do vetor 1: 7
Digite o 4° número do vetor 1: 9

Digite o 0° número do vetor 2: 2
Digite o 1° número do vetor 2: 4
Digite o 2° número do vetor 2: 6
Digite o 3° número do vetor 2: 8
Digite o 4° número do vetor 2: 10
```

A saída esperada

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

A saída gerada

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

```
using static System.Console;

namespace TesteVetor
{
    class Program4
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vetor1 = new int[5];
            var vetor2 = new int[5];
            var vetor3 = new int[10];
            int i = 0, j = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < vetor1.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Write($"Digite o {i}° número do vetor 1: ");
                vetor1[i] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            }

            WriteLine();

            for (i = 0; i < vetor2.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Write($"Digite o {i}° número do vetor 2: ");
                vetor1[i] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                vetor3[i] = vetor1[i];
                j++;
                vetor3[i] = vetor2[i];
                j++;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < vetor3.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                WriteLine($"{vetor3[i]}");
            }
            ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vou tentar resolver os outros problemas do código, porque eu já ensinei o certo, mas aparentemente não importa, mas fica a dica para quem for ler esta resposta que este código não deve ser usado desta forma (tem diversos outros códigos aqui no site que mostram uma forma melhor), então tem dois problemas para resolver:

- usar a variável `j` que foi criado, incrementada, mas não usado no `*array*.
- no segundo laço guardar os dados em `vetor2` e não em `vetor1` que passa por cima do que estava em `vetor1` e `vetor2`fica sem dados.

Assim:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace TesteVetor {
    class Program4 {
        static void Main() {
            var vetor1 = new int[5];
            var vetor2 = new int[5];
            var vetor3 = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < vetor1.GetLength(0); i++) {
                Write($"Digite o {i}° número do vetor 1: ");
                vetor1[i] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            }
            WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < vetor2.GetLength(0); i++) {
                Write($"Digite o {i}° número do vetor 2: ");
                vetor2[i] = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            }
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                vetor3[j++] = vetor1[i];
                vetor3[j++] = vetor2[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < vetor3.GetLength(0); i++) WriteLine($"{vetor3[i]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nMxe4q). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4XzWXi). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Join.cs).

Comment: Não sabia que dava pra usar duas variáveis de inicialização de uma só vez no `for`.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, 
amigo colocando seu código no VS, verifiquei que há algumas inconsistências, tais como ao solicitar ao usuário digitar os dados do vetor 2, está sendo gravado no vetor 1, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

sobre o resultado incorreto é devido ao for que preenche o vetor 3, pois vc está incrementando a variável "j", mas não está usando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo de como deverá ser aplicado a correção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que existem formas mais elegantes de resolver, mas seguindo o seu raciocínio, segue imagem abaixo de como seu código deverá ficar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Favor não colocar imagens dos códigos e sim colá-los aqui e formatar corretamente.